# SQL Server and difficulty generating column with unique values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, and I want a new column that calculates the following:

- If it has an ‘Exec’ value for category, it takes the ‘enddate’.
- If it has an ‘Scop’ value for category, it takes the ‘start date’.

This new column calculates the number of months between these two.

I want SQL to do the calculation for a given id, so each id will have different values calculated.

At the moment it takes the minimum enddate and minimum 'startdate' for the entire table.

```
SELECT
    id, category, startdate, enddate,
    CASE
        WHEN id = id 
            THEN DATEDIFF(month, 
                          (SELECT MIN(enddate) from [A].[PP] where category = 'Exec'),
                          (SELECT MIN(startdate) from [A].[PP] where category = 'Scop')) --AS datemodify
            ELSE NULL
    END
FROM
    [A].[PP]
WHERE
    startdate IS NOT NULL
    AND (category = 'Exec' OR category = 'Scop')
ORDER BY 
    id ASC
```

Results it produces at the moment:

| id | category | startdate | enddate | NewCOlumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Scop | 2022-11-1 | 2022-10-1 | 11 |
| 1 | Exec | 2023-11-1 | 2023-10-1 | 11 |
| 2 | Scop | 2022-11-1 | 2022-10-1 | 11 |
| 2 | Exec | 2023-11-1 | 2023-09-1 | 11 |

The results I want:

| id | category | startdate | enddate | NewCOlumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Scop | 2021-11-1 | 2022-10-1 | 24 |
| 1 | Exec | 2023-11-1 | 2023-11-1 | 24 |
| 2 | Scop | 2022-11-1 | 2022-10-1 | 11 |
| 2 | Exec | 2023-11-1 | 2023-09-1 | 11 |

Comment: Can you post us sample data. I cant figure out how can you have 10 months difference between `2022-10-1`  and  `2022-11-1`

Comment: Hi Anel, thanks for the reply! I've just corrected it in the code...Cheers

Comment: Currently your produced and wanted results are the same. Based on your text description I think you want 1 line per ID, with the Scop Start Date, the Exec End Date, and then a date difference between them

Comment: Thanks Ricky - it should have updated ah!

Comment: are you still sure your expected results are correct? you want 2 lines per ID, 1 for Scop and 1 for Exec, showing both StartDate and EndDate for both, but do the DateDiff across different rows? Also the DateDiff for ID 1 is only 23 months

Comment: Hi Ricky, that's right - I attempted to follow the easiest method to get the result... The alternative is to have an output that is an 'id' column and 'newcolumn' which is also fine. I suppose what i struggled with was that it uses inputs from two different rows... but surely there is a way to either get the result i just explained or the one above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments I'm not sure you still know you want as your output so I've come up with two different versions.

Here's how I'm created a version of your data set:

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable (ID, Category, StartDate, EndDate)
VALUES (1, 'Scop', '2021-11-01', '2022-10-01'),
       (1, 'Exec', '2023-11-01', '2023-10-01'),
       (2, 'Scop', '2022-11-01', '2022-10-01'),
       (2, 'Exec', '2023-11-01', '2023-10-01');
```

This is the first version, this created your two lines per ID but hacks the StartDate and EndDate from different rows. This works by selecting all of the data straight out of the temp table, it then goes on to say if the row is Category = Scop then do a `DateDiff` between the StartDate and then fetches the EndDate from a subquery where the IDs match and the Category = Exec (it also has the same logic applied but the other way around for where the initial Category = Exec):

```
SELECT TT.ID,
       TT.Category,
       TT.StartDate,
       TT.EndDate,
       CASE
           WHEN TT.Category = 'Scop' THEN DATEDIFF(M, TT.StartDate, (SELECT EndDate FROM #TempTable WHERE Category = 'Exec' AND ID = TT.ID))
           ELSE CASE
                    WHEN TT.Category = 'Exec' THEN DATEDIFF(M, (SELECT StartDate FROM #TempTable WHERE Category = 'Scop' AND ID = TT.ID), TT.EndDate)
                END
       END AS DateDiffCalc
FROM #TempTable AS TT;
```

This version compresses the IDs to a single row, it initially only fetches Scop data, but then joins back to itself using ID and specifices now to get the Exec data only. Now you can `DateDiff` between the Scop StartDate and the Exec EndDate

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID,
                t1.Category,
                t1.StartDate,
                T2.Category,
                T2.EndDate,
                DATEDIFF(M, t1.StartDate, T2.EndDate) AS DateDiffCalc
FROM #TempTable AS t1
     INNER JOIN #TempTable AS T2 ON T2.ID = T2.ID AND T2.Category = 'Exec'
WHERE t1.Category = 'Scop'
ORDER BY t1.ID;
```